# Is it possible to get parent threadID from child?

Tags: c, pthreads, llvm

I am trying to add instrumentation into my code that will print out something like

'Thread 1 forks Thread 2'

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: It's questionable whether it shows enough research effort but it's quite clear what's being asked and answerable.

Comment: Are you doing it in LLVM IR?

Comment: Give part of code where you are trying to print it?

Comment: I want to generate a complete trace of the program execution. I intercepted calls to pthread_create in a opt phase that I wrote. Basically, I just go through all the instructions and instrument lock/unlock, load/store etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminology correction: one thread may *create* another thread, not *fork*, which is usually
used to mention one process forking another.

No, a thread has no way to get another thread's identifier. On Linux, you can check if `gettid() == getpid()` to find if it's the  main thread. Solaris has [thr_main()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0630/6j9vkb8ks/index.html) to identify if the caller is main thread or not. FreeBSD has [pthread_main_np()](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pthread_main_np&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.1-RELEASE) for the same purpose.

But there's no way to identify parent-child relationship between any threads. Any thread can create more threads. You'll have to use pass the thread identifiers around when creating threads or use global data structure to maintain this information.