# how to get the parent id in c++ with thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parent, parentid

I want to know how I can get the parent id from a created thread.
I had the idea that i make an id variable in the main function and give it as a parameter when i create the thread, but it doesn't work.
Or can i get the parent id otherwise?

My code:

```
void first(std::thread::id id) {
//do something
cout << id << endl;
}

int main() {

std::thread::id id = std::this_thread::get_id();
std::thread thread(first, id);

return 0;

}
```

What are your ideas?

Comment: Why does this code not work?

Comment: You have to join your thread before the program terminates with `thread.join();` before the `return 0;` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void first(std::thread::id id) {
    std::cout << "ID in thread: "<< id << std::endl;
    std::thread::id ownID = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "ID of thread: " << ownID << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread::id id = std::this_thread::get_id();
    std::cout << "ID in main: " << id << std::endl;
    std::thread thread(first, id);
    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

generates the output:

```
ID in main: 1
ID in thread: 1
ID of thread: 2
```

If this isn't the desired output, please clarify your question.
By the way: Your idea seems to be the best solution, because even the system does not keep track of parent threads. [Is it possible to get parent threadID from child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005366/is-it-possible-to-get-parent-threadid-from-child)